# image displayed in firebase recycleradapter is dissappering during the onclick

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, android-recyclerview

I displayed my stored images in firebase in recyclerview using firebase recycler adapter and I have given the on touch listener to the images so I get the like from the user, but on doubleclick on image my image infact my complete single view of that image eg. likebutton, commentslikes, profileview of that image is dissappeared only for that image so why this is happening?

Comment: show the on double tap listener

Comment: double tap listner means on touch listner in that i have given the condition on double tap

Comment: yes i mean show the code..

Comment: I will upload it in 2-3 hours now I am in class